# javascript -- Convert date string to another format?

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have date string like `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS` which is PST timezone, I need to change it to UTC format `2016-07-28T17:22:51.916Z`. How can I do that?

Comment: Have you made an attempt or looked at built-in conversion solutions?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done pretty easily in JS:

```
var pstDate = new Date(myValidPstDateString);

// ISO is always in UTC time
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString
console.log(pstDate.toISOString());
```

Comment: it will fail with "invalid date"

Comment: The date you put into it does need to be valid in the first place. What's your input string?

Comment: 2016-07-25 11:58:33.299

Comment: Works for me no problem... `new Date("2016-07-25 11:58:33.299")`

Comment: the issue happens at pstDate.toISOString() RangeError: invalid date

Comment: What browser are you on? I'm having no issues doing this in Chrome console.